# Getting "newline inside string" while reading the csv file in Python?

Tags: python, django, csv, python-2.7

I have this utils.py file in Django Architecture:

```
def range_data(ip):
    r = []
    f = open(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, 'static', 'csv ', 
                          'GeoIPCountryWhois.csv'))
    for num,row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        if row[0] <= ip <= row[1]:
            r.append([r[4]])
            return r
        else:
            continue
    return r
```

Here the ip parameter is just the IPv4 Address, I am using open source MAXMIND `GeoIPCountrywhois.csv` file.

Some starting content of `GeopIOCountrywhois.csv`:

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP","Japan"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","CN","China"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","16809983","JP","Japan"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16809984","16842751","TH","Thailand"
```

I have also read about the issue, But didn't found so much understandable. Would you please help me to solve that error?

According to my method in utils, I am checking country name of paasing parameter `IP` address to the method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can preprocess the csv by removing the newline like below.

   ```
   import csv

   content = open("GeoIPCountryWhois.csv", "r").read().replace('\r\n','\n')

   with open("GeoIPCountryWhois2.csv", "w") as g:
       g.write(content)
   ```

   Then Use GeoIPCountryWhois2 for csv reader.
2. A wild Guess using a lineterminator may solve your problem

   ```
   for num,row in enumerate(csv.reader(f,lineterminator='\n'))
   ```

   See also: http://docs.python.org/lib/csv-fmt-params.html

Comment: The `lineterminator` keyword argument to `csv.reader()` is explicitly documented as being ignored. You need to open file objects in binary mode so the `csv` module can handle newlines correctly itself.

Comment: The link you provide is broken!

Comment: This was useful.  However, I found that the following slight alteration worked: `f.read().replace('\r',' ')`.  Could be system-dependent I guess.

Answer (score 14):

had similar problem earlier today, there was an end quote missing from a line and the solution is by instructing `reader` to perform no special processing of quote characters (`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`).

Comment: this is def the correct answer for the error when it's caused by unended quotes as was my case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This solved my problem, where the accepted answer did not. I was getting a similar error

Comment: This only works if the quoting isn't being used to escape delimiters present in the column values. With `csv.QUOTE_NONE` you'll still have to strip the quotes manually.

Answer (score 4):

You must open your files as binary:

```
def range_data(ip):
    r = []
    f = open(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, 'static', 'csv ', 
                          'GeoIPCountryWhois.csv'), 'rb')
    for num,row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        # Your things.
```

Note the `'rb'` mode there; otherwise the file could be opened with native line endings, and the CSV reader doesn't handle the various forms very well. Certainly the copy of `GeoIPCountryWhois.csv` that *I* downloaded has clean `\n` line endings.

This is documented for the [.reader() method](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

If, however, your csv file is so corrupted as to still contain unexpected newline characters in unexpected places, use this `file` subclass instead as a stop-gap measure:

```
class CleanlinesFile(file):
    def next(self):
        line = super(CleanlinesFile, self).next()
        return line.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '') + '\n'
```

This class guarantees there will be no newlines anywhere in the returned results except as the very last character (just the way the csv module wants it). Use it instead of the `open` call; the `'rb'` mode modifier becomes optional in this case:

```
def range_data(ip):
    r = []
    f = CleanlinesFile(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, 'static', 'csv ', 
                          'GeoIPCountryWhois.csv'))
    for num,row in enumerate(csv.reader(f)):
        # Your things.
```