# How do I skip a line if the data in this line is not correct while parsing csv file using csv module in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create an Excel file out of a csv file. Here is how my csv file looks like:

```
    |T|,|T|,|T|,|T|
    |A|,|B|,|C|,|D|
    |E|,|F|,|G|,|H|
    |I|,|J|,|K|,|L|
    |M|,|N|,|O
    |Q|,|R|,|S|,|T|
    |U|,|V|,|W|,|X|
    |Y|,|Z
    |A|,|B|,|C|,|D|
```

I am using , as separator | as quote character and using following script to generate file:

```
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
mydelimiter = ','
myquotechar = '|'
with open('abcd.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=mydelimiter, quotechar=myquotechar)
    workbook = Workbook('abcd.xlsx', {'strings_to_urls': False})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(r,c,col)
    workbook.close()
```

What is happening here is that while parsing line number 5, reader continues to find next quote character and delimiter in next line which inserts line numer 5 and 6 in single line in excel file. Line number 5 in my excel file looks like

```
    Line No. 5: M   N   "O{newline character here}Q|"   R   S   T
```

My question is how can we skip a line if it isn't in correct format or stop reader from considering next row but end the line there only instead.
Data in my csv doesn't have {newline character} but for some rows don't have ending quote character and some columns (in line number 5, 3rd column should have been |O| and 4th column |P| is missing).
Here is what I want my excel file to look like:

```
    Line No. 5: M   N   O (I am good with or without this line in excel.)
    Line No. 6: Q   R   S   T
```

and as suggested in link provided by Arne S.

    `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=mydelimiter, quotechar=myquotechar, lineterminator='\n')`

doesn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "newline inside string" while reading the csv file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362667/getting-newline-inside-string-while-reading-the-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: Actually I want exact opposite of what is asked in above link. My data doesn't have a new line character and I don't want to continue to next line. By just providing lineterminator as '\n' to `csv.reader()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your row for the correct number of elements before processing.

```
with open('abcd.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=mydelimiter, quotechar=myquotechar)
    workbook = Workbook('abcd.xlsx', {'strings_to_urls': False})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        # would only work if we have constant number of columns for all rows.
        if len(row) != 4: continue
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(r,c,col)
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: I get TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len(), r is integer type so `len()` is not applicable.

Comment: I have never used enumerate, so the syntax is unfamiliar.  If row is the actual row of data, then use `if len(row) != 4: continue` and see if that works. If it does, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That Works (omits line from excel), thanks. I had already found a solution will post here. I would request you to edit your answer too (r -> row).

Answer (score 0):

After digging into csv module documentation I found my answer.

We can force csv reader in python not to perform any special handling of quote characters by using following line while creating reader object.

`reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=mydelimiter, quotechar=myquotechar, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)`

csv.QUOTE_NONE instructs reader not to perform any special processing of quote characters.

This way we won't skip incomplete rows but will have reduced number of columns in excel for those particular rows.

Also answer by @{James C. Taylor} works if we don't want incomplete data at all and you have fixed number of columns in your csv file.